# Adicionar ponto final de cada linha

Tags: sublime-text-2

Eu queria saber se tem algum comando no sublime ou algum outro editor, que insira algum carácter pre determinado.

Pois tenho um codigo html que preciso adicionar a String, tipo assim:

body += "   ";

Ai eu queria adicionar no inicio de cada linha o seguinte codigo: **body += "**

E no final de cada linha, adicionar:   **";**

Porem são muitas linhas, e fazer isso manualmente vai dar trabalho =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer é substituir os finais de linha do arquivo por:
 **";[fim-de-linha]body += "** 
e depois ajustar a primeira e a última linhas.

Onde [fim-de-linha] é o(s) caractere(s) especial correspondente do formato de arquivo que você estiver usando.

Pode ser feito no Notepad++ usando a função de substituir habitual.
Basta marcar a opção "Extendido" no campo "Modo de Busca" e indicar os finais de linha com os caracteres correspondentes '\n' ou '\r' '\n'.